# DataGridColumn Change to ComboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have list `usrdetails` that I'm using as my data source for my `DataGridview`. 
Two questions:

1. How can I change the column type for the 3rd Column in my `DataGridview` from a `DataGridTextBoxColumn` to a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`?
2. Once I've changed the 3rd column to a `ComboBox` how would I populate with list of strings?

---

```
public class usrInfo
{
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string seclev { get; set; }
    public string isext { get; set; }

    public usrInfo(string userID, string username, string group, string seclev, string isext)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
        this.group = group;
        this.seclev = seclev;
        this.isext = isext;
    }
}

public static List<usrInfo> usrdetails = new List<usrInfo>();

private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = usrdetails;
        for (int i = 0; i < secgrps.Count; i++)
          groups.Add(secgrps[i].ToString());
        comboColumn.Name ="Security Group";
        comboColumn.DataSource = groups;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, comboColumn);
        usrdetails.Add(new usrInfo("domain\\userID", "User Name", "RIGSITE ONLY Wellsite Leader", "7", "Y"));
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        if (usrdetails.Count > -1)
            num_users = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to your `dataGridView1` control and assign its `DataSource` property to the collection of strings you want.

```
var myStringCollection = new[] {"String1", "String2", "String3"};

var comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboColumn.Name = "MyComboColumn";
comboColumn.DataSource = myStringCollection; //This sets the source of drop down items
```

Then insert it into your grid:

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns["MyComboColumn"] == null)
{
    //The int value as first parameter of Insert() is the desired Column Index
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, comboColumn);
}
```

Comment: {
    var comboColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    comboColumn.Name = "Security Group";
    comboColumn.DataSource = secgrps;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, comboColumn);
}

I added the presentation framework dll as a reference, so I could add the using system.windows.control, however, I comboColumn does contain a definition/method for .Name or .Datasource. What am I missing?

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2,ComboColumn) says its an invalid arg

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?  You shouldn't need presentation framework, just System.Windows.Forms for DataGridView.  If this is ASP.Net or WPF then this will change the solution.  Please verify.

Comment: Its a windows form, but if I don't have using system.windows.controls referenced. comboColumn.NAME and .DATASOURCE aren't valid. In fact the only .Header and .Itemsource is what found for the comboBox type.

Comment: Can you please post your new code exactly as it is, including the comboBoxColumn code you are working on?  I have a feeling you have syntax or type errors.  Please post this as an addition to your question.  Not in a comment.

Comment: Okay. I've updated the code in this question. Errors are as follows -> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.Insert(int, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn)' has some invalid arguments

Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridComboBoxColumn' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn'

Comment: Remove Presentation Framework from your project.  You don't need it, that is only for WPF applications.  Make sure in your Form class you have `using System.Windows.Forms`.  Once those are done, this should work.  The only thing I can think of is that you used the wrong `DataGridView` when you created your project.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET FrameWork 4 is what I have as well. Visual Studio 2010. Output type Windows Application. My base OS is Windows 8.1.
this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView(); Is where its creating from. if I change DataGridComboBoxColumn to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, then .name and .datasource work.

Comment: Yes thats what my example showed. Not datagrid but datagridview